# Prepend 0 to a single digit if it leads, ends, or exists in the middle of a string separate from another character

Tags: php

Examples of "sentences" that would require a prepend of 0:

`5 this is 3` becomes `05 this is 03`

`44 this is 2` becomes `44 this is 02` (note 44 is not prepended because it is not a single digit)

`this 4 is` becomes `this 04 is`

---

Examples of "sentences" that would not get a prepend of 0:

`44 this is`

`22 this3 is` (note 3 is not prepended because it exists as part of a string)

`this is5`

I tried coming up with a regex and failed miserably.

Comment: There are lots of ways of accomplishing what you want. A good starting point however would be the code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = '5 this is 3';

$replaced = preg_replace('~(?<=\s|^)\d(?=\D|$)~', '0\\0', $str); // 05 this is 03
```

The regular expression means: every digit (`\d`) that is preceded by a space or a beginning of a string `(?<=\s|^)` and followed by not digit or the end of a string `(?=\D|$)` - replace with itself prepended by `0`

Live demo: http://ideone.com/3B7W0n

Answer (score 3):

Use the following pattern `'/((?<= |^)[0-9](?![0-9]))/'` with `preg_replace()`:

I wrote a little test script:

```
$pattern = '/((?<= |^)[0-9](?![0-9]))/';
$replacement = "0$1";

$tests = array(
    '5 this is 3' => '05 this is 03',
    '44 this is 2' => '44 this is 02',
    'this 4 is' => 'this 04 is',
    '44 this is' => '44 this is',
    'this is5' => 'this is5'
);

foreach($tests as $orginal => $expected) {
    $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $orginal);
    if($result !== $expected) {
        $msg  = 'Test Failed: "' . $orginal . '"' . PHP_EOL;
        $msg .= 'Expected: "' . $expected . '"' . PHP_EOL;
        $msg .= 'Got     : "' . $result . '"'. PHP_EOL;
        echo 'error' . $msg;
    } else {
        $original . '=>' . $result . PHP_EOL;
    }      
}
```

Explanation:

I use [assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to make sure only digits `[0-9]`that are:

- not followed by a digit itself: `(?![0-9])`
- and prepended by a whitespace or the start of the line: `((?<= |^)`

will get prefixed with a `0`.

Comment: Omg, guys, why do you upvote an answer that doesn't even work for the most trivial requirement?? "5 this is 3"

Comment: what do you think `[$ ]` does? It is a characters set of `$` sign and a space

Comment: Hi @zerkms. Yes i thought its the start of the line or a whitespace. Currently trying to workaround this.

Comment: not even near to that )) And what is `[ \.]`? It's a space or a "dot" character

Comment: still wrong `[^ ]` - is a character set of "everything except of space".

Comment: I know!! it were just typos.. But why does the current version not work?

Comment: because `[^a]` - is "everything except of `a`", `[^ ]` - is everything except of space. First - get it worked, second - post on SO. In this particular order.

Comment: Agreed with @zerkms. It its current form this answer looks more like a too-localized question.

Comment: Updated that.. Still confusing for me.. Note that all errors were typos as I updated the post after tests. I currently don't know why the current version not works. will investigate this

Comment: "Note that all errors were typos" --- all the errors were mistakes. Typo is when you pressed wrong key, a error - is when the solution is incorrect by definition.

Comment: yeah or when you are hurried because of 1000 comments. Not having time to open up  a vim editor and check whats wrong

Comment: @hek2mgl: 1. get it worked 2. post on stackoverflow. "or when you are hurried" ---- no one required you to post something just to be first. It's actually a terrible idea to post some cr*p just to be first and modify it after.

Comment: `[ ^]` isn't better, since it means "space or `^` character". The `^` string will match it, beginning of the string won't

Comment: @zerkms Sorry for the confusion. Check my update. Like I said, the confusion arises mainly about little errors, which I'm aware of. I just misstyped the regex in case of hurry. **The main remaining question for me is:** why acts a `[ ^]` not like a `( |^)`? I would have expected this.

Comment: @hek2mgl: now better, but still - Have you tried to run it with ` 5 this is 3`? The solution should transform it to ` 05 this is 03` Note on the space before. Accuracy is the best programmer's character, you should follow the requirements as correct as possible. To resume: current solution breaks the original data - it removes extra spaces (while it shouldn't take care of spaces at all)

Comment: @zerkms because `05 this is 03` as expected :D (not the case when trying yours ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl: you're too inattentive "5 this is 3          "  should become "05 this is 03         ". Do you see spaces in the end? There was nothing in the requirement about removing extra spaces from the end of the string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28481/discussion-between-zerkms-and-hek2mgl)

Comment: This is is not part of the question

Comment: @hek2mgl: how is it different from mine now?

Comment: I didn't had a look at yours before posting my update. You can believe me! I see, you are using assertions too. Didn't know about them before. Cool stuff.. However my regex is at least a bit different. You can see my explanation. I'm pretty happy to get it working, and happy to know about assertions now. Now 06:18 am CEST. Thanks!!

Comment: @hek2mgl: to get this night even more tricky - http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html - after this your brains will melt :-)

Comment: @zekms. Understood, you are using positive quantifiers only what makes your regex more performant. will upvote this solution! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-regex way of achieving it:

```
$line = "this 4 is";

$words = explode(' ', $line);
foreach ($words as &$word) {
    if (ctype_digit($word)) {
        $word = str_pad($word, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}

echo implode(' ', $words);
```